# Maintaining name value pairs with Spinner just like HTML select box?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner that shows locations name data of course which are strings.

Now the thing is when user selects them I require the Longitude-Latitude value of the location to pass further.

Sending that location string back to `Geolocater` and getting its Longitude-Latitude values again would be a redundant thing.

Isn't there a way a I can maintain the type `double` values of Longitude-Latitude connected to each string item in the spinner. Just like it happens in html `select` box?
Is there a pattern to do this, i mean it seems like a very popular task occuring in apps like foursquare etc. everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite simple, though they're not exactly name/value pairs as in HTML.

A Spinner actually displays its values by calling `getView()` on an Adapter. `ArrayAdapter<T>`, by default, applies `toString()` to every item -- the items don't necessarily have to be Strings *themselves*. So you can define a new class, say:

```
public class SpinnerItem {
    String name;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then create an `ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem>` instead of an `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

This will display the names in the Spinner. And to get the longitude/latitude values you just need to use `adapter.getItem(position)` (for example from an `OnItemSelectedListener`).

*(If you're using a custom adapter then the solution is essentially the same, except that you would be overriding `getView()` in the adapter instead of implementing `toString()` in the item).*